# Using CONTAINS to find JSON key and value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12.1

I am trying to figure out best way to search for certain key value in json. I created context index on column and I am querying where with contains:

```
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.value
FROM
    OD.DOKUMENT d 
WHERE 
    CONTAINS (d.VALUE, '"key":"123424') > 0
```

However result is not as expected. I can't figure out how Oracle searches values, clearly it is not similar to standard

```
LIKE %"key":"123424%
```

Is there a better way to accomplish that? I can't confirm it in documentation however i suppose that oracle is looking for "key" as well as "123424".

Unfortunately I am not able to upgrade my database version from 12.1.0 to 12.2 (where json is supported).

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: CONTAINS is an ORACLE TEXT operator, it requires specific indexing and it looks for words and your target contains quotes, column,... which are probably considered as separators of words... regexp function will be probably better for your needs.